# How to remove div around an image in typo3?

Tags: html, typo3, typo3-7.x

I added an image in typo3. It showed up with extra div in page.

```
  <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-center csc-textpic-above">
    <div class="csc-textpic-imagewrap" data-csc-images="1" data-csc-cols="2">
        <div class="csc-textpic-center-outer">
            <div class="csc-textpic-center-inner">
            <figure class="csc-textpic-image csc-textpic-last">
                <img src="fileadmin/user_upload/aetuts.jpg" width="200" height="50" alt=""></figure>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want something like this

```
 <img src="fileadmin/user_upload/aetuts.jpg" width="200" height="50" alt="">
```

with no extra wrapper.

I can do something like this for removing extra wapper around content.

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap >
```

How to do it for image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Regarding your specific question

The following code should remove all wraps around the image. Keep in mind that this also removes the positioning and floating abilities.

```
# Remove some wraps
tt_content.image.20.imageStdWrap.dataWrap >
tt_content.image.20.imageStdWrapNoWidth.dataWrap >
tt_content.image.20.imageColumnStdWrap.dataWrap >

# Redefine the layout switch with only one default case
tt_content.image.20.layout >
tt_content.image.20.layout = CASE
tt_content.image.20.layout.key.field = imageorient
tt_content.image.20.layout.default = TEXT
tt_content.image.20.layout.default.value = ###IMAGES### ###TEXT###

# Remove the wrap around the image subtext
tt_content.textpic.20.text.wrap = |

# Define a new rendering method without wraps
tt_content.image.20.rendering.noWraps {
  imageRowStdWrap.dataWrap = |
  noRowsStdWrap.wrap =
  oneImageStdWrap.dataWrap = |
  imgTagStdWrap.wrap = |
  editIconsStdWrap.wrap = |
  caption.wrap = |
}
# Set this as active rendering method
tt_content.image.20.renderMethod = noWraps
```

.

#### How to do that for any content element

1. Use the *Template* view in Typo3
2. Go to the page with your template
3. Edit your template
4. Select the *Typoscript-Object-Browser* at the top (instead of *Info/Edit*)
5. Use the search form to find a wrap, e.g. "csc-textpic"
6. Identify the wraps or templates that you want to remove
7. Overwrite or delete `>` them in you Typoscript code

Comment: It removed extra wrappers, but width and height attributes are still there.

Comment: Just follow my steps and it will lead you to `tt_content.image.20.1.layout.default.element = <img src="###SRC###" ###ALTPARAMS###>`. I won't add it to my answer though, since your desired output was *including* width and height.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this was really an awesome way to search things.