# TYPO3 - How to add a placeholder to an input field?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In TYPO3 (7.2.0) using the standard template engine, is there a way to add a placeholder attribute to the standard mail form text input?

At the moment I am using JavaScript to convert the labels into placeholders, but I am open to suggestions on a better way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested solution of @biesior does only work for EXT:form 7.4 and higher (see [changelog](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6/typo3/sysext/core/Documentation/Changelog/7.4/Feature-61308-AllowPlaceholderAttribute.rst)). The supplied picture shows the form wizard of TYPO3 7.5 or 7.6. In 7.2 you won't find any placeholder attribute in the wizard.

I recommend updating to TYPO3 7.6 since this version includes a major rewrite of EXT:form. You will be able to use fluid templates to customize your forms. Furthermore HTML5 attributes are possible. Before the rewrite the set of allowed attributes was quite limited. Now you are able to add all attributes you can think of (for example "data-"). See [changelog](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6/typo3/sysext/core/Documentation/Changelog/7.5/Feature-69401-AdoptFormToSupportTheExtbaseFluidMVCStack.rst).

If you have any questions regarding EXT:form join the channel on Slack. If you don't know Slack yet, check out the [invite function](https://forger.typo3.org/slack).

Comment: If you understand German, I can recommend these posts: http://www.tritum.de/agentur/neuigkeiten/artikel/tritum-entwickelt-an-typo3-extform-part-1/ and http://www.tritum.de/agentur/neuigkeiten/artikel/tritum-entwickelt-an-typo3-extform-part-2/

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not my installation and I will not be able to change it. If I add the Fluid extension will that enable me to change the forms the way I want, or would I still need to update TYPO3?

Comment: You should really try to update your system to a current 7.6. The version 7.2 will not receive any security updates and there have already been some issues in TYPO3 7 (see https://typo3.org/teams/security/security-bulletins/typo3-core/).

You can try to extract EXT:form from 7.6 and copy it to /typo3conf/ext/. That way you could possibly override the older core version. If you're using composer, it's a little bit different.

Answer (score 1):

During form fields editing you have many properties, also `Placeholder`

[image]

in text version it will be:

```
10 = TEXTLINE
10 {
    type = text
    class = foo-class
    id = foo-id
    name = foo
    placeholder = Hmmm?
    required = required
    label {
        value = My Field
    }
}
```